# How to Verify Fingerprint of a .gpg File

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, gnupg, fingerprint

I was following [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) instruction to install VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine.

As per instruction I registered the public key:

```
wget -O- https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor --yes --output /usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg
```

They state that the fingerprint for `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` is

```
B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
```

Now, I am trying to verify the fingerprint but I have trouble extracting the fingerprint from the .gpg file.

For example, if I use the following command, it outputs some information but not the fingerprint:

```
gpg --with-fingerprint /usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg
```

What command do I have to use to extract the fingerprint from the `oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg` file?

Comment: You should not need a fingerprint to install VBOX on Linux or Windows.  Lots of computers do not have fingerprints.   Try again without using fingerprints.

Comment: @John Yes, it is not necessary for installation. However, I wanted to test and see whether the fingerprint of the registered key matches the one they stated in their installation instruction. So, it was more out of curiosity but I guess, it is also a way to authenticate the public key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome Tando to Superuser,

You can check the fingerprint of the pubic key in the keyring with the following command:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg --fingerprint
```

Comment: Thank you! I've also just found another command that works with **gpg 2.2.19**: `gpg --show-keys --with-fingerprint /usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg`. The `--with-fingerprint` flag is not necessary but it makes the fingerprint better readable by dividing it in groups of 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using *gpg* version `2.2.27`

```
gpg --version

# output
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.4
```

Download the current `.asc` file from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads as of this writing (2023-03-22):

```
wget https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

The VirtualBox website currently states:

> The key fingerprint for oracle_vbox_2016.asc is
>
> ```
> B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
> Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
> ```

The following commands all allow to verify this information, each with different formatting:

```
gpg --show-keys --with-fingerprint --keyid-format=short oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output:

```
pub   rsa4096/2980AECF 2016-04-22 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
uid                    Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096/920E471F 2016-04-22 [E]
```

---

```
gpg --show-keys --with-fingerprint oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output:

```
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [SC]
      B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
uid                      Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [E]
```

---

```
gpg --show-keys oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output:

```
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [SC]
      B9F8D658297AF3EFC18D5CDFA2F683C52980AECF
uid                      Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [E]
```

---

```
gpg --show-keys --with-colons oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output ("*The `--with-colons` option emits the output in a stable, machine-parseable format, which is intended for use by scripts and other programs.*"):

```
pub:-:4096:1:A2F683C52980AECF:1461318881:::-:::scESC::::::23::0:
fpr:::::::::B9F8D658297AF3EFC18D5CDFA2F683C52980AECF:
uid:-::::1461318881::CA5D570DDFDB695A0301885765DD8E285368742C::Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>::::::::::0:
sub:-:4096:1:AD18C79D920E471F:1461318881::::::e::::::23:
fpr:::::::::31DD01EB8C64DF3D12E7BC97AD18C79D920E471F:
```